# Http Client Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, httpclient, integration, webapi

Hello i have an issue that i try to get response from an api. if i try it in my localhost, all is alright but when i try to get publish and push the code into the server. i got an error like below;

"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. "

I also read similar issue related to this topic. They solved their problem with the code below;

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11|SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

but when i put the code my constructor. I still get same failed error above;

i am gonna very glad if somebody helps

here is my code when i try access the api;

```
    public async Task<PgBranchList> GetBranchListByCityId(int? cityId)
    {
        PgBranchList pgBranchObj = new PgBranchList();
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Auth-Key", AuthKey);
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(PilotGarageUri + "list_dealers");
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "city_id", cityId.ToString() } };
            var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(request.RequestUri, encodedContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                pgBranchObj = responseString.GetJsonObject<PgBranchList>();
            }
        }
        return pgBranchObj;
    }
```

Comment: Could it be something low-level, such as ip filtering by the API?

Comment: Hi Jesper, could be.  then how to fix ?

Comment: Ask the API owner why you cannot connect from the server... Unless of course it is your own API :)

Comment: no the API owner is not ours. :) but the interesting thing is that i can connect API method and see results via postman and run code in localhost but when publishing and put the code dll into the server, i got error. I think i forgot small thing but maybe some restriction is prevent me to see result in the API

Comment: What happens if you run postman from the server?

Comment: you are right, when i set postman the server as you said then i realized that our system admins put restriction access API now i opened ticket to admin to remove restriction.  i didn't doubt the API cant be access because the server has internet. your comment was helpful. Thanks @JesperMygind :)

Comment: No problem. Networking issues can be quite annoying for us programmers :).